# SQL SERVER If Else Specific User

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure where I pass in Users, say A,B,C as a parameter.

I want to execute specific code for a certain users and different code for other two users. Is there any way to achieve it?

I have a query like this in mind:

```
If(@User='A')
{
    // do something    
}    
else    
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, both the SP and how it's called. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I would downvote this question but your score is a perfect 42 and I hate to mess it...

Comment: @ZoharPeled In that case he already has his answer. But yes, please show us some details because your description is all but clear. The code you posted isn't even SQL to begin with.

Comment: Also, now the comments are upvoted 3,2,1, 0... Smile, everyone, I want to take a picture :-)

Comment: @Tanner if you upvote my second comment and I (and one more) upvoted your second comment, and this comment will get 3 upvotes... that will be a picture worth taking... but I think we made enough noise here for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty basic SQL code, you don't use curly braces, you use `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
DECLARE @user NVARCHAR(1) = 'A'

IF @user = 'A'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'hi user: ' + @user
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'You are not user A - you are user: ' + @user
END
```

Comment: But while Executing in SP for Example  Say I am trying EXEC SP_NAME 'A,B' I need If part to be Executed for 'A' and Else Part for Other User.

Comment: I have Used Split String for Separating comma separated values but the main problem I face is that when I execute the SP with A,B as Parameters the Else Part gets executed for both the users but i want if part for User A and Else Part for user B.

Comment: Split your string, loop over all your individual users and execute the code required for each individual user.

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran, you're comments here tell me that the question above isn't really the question you're asking. Post your actual code, with the actual results, and an explanation of what you need to have happen instead of what did happen.